# Error 403 encountered when POSTing text content containing URI

Tags: javascript, php

I have a web application with a WYSIWYG text editor (CKEDITOR) that should enable author to create rich text content with images and links to documents (PDF).
The contents of the related text area is being posted as formData to my web application server and I have an issue with the WAF (Web Application Firewall).

I often encounter the 403 - Forbidden response in reply to submitting the form, based on the contents of the CKEDITOR textarea it seems.

I am looking for a trusted approach to encoding the rich text contents before the form is submitted and later decoded server-side.

Now I have seen and tried some Javascript methods:

window.btoa
encodeURIComponent

But I encounter issues server side when it comes to retrieving the original contents - I'm working on PHP 5.6 server-side

Can someone suggest an end-to-end approach to encoding and decoding text with Javascript and PHP technologies please?

Thx

Comment: `HTTP 403 is a standard HTTP status code communicated to clients by an HTTP server to indicate that the server understood the request, but will not fulfill it.` - so I don't think it's the encoding, it's probably a (file system) permission issue (on the server)

Comment: What I observe is that whenever there are some html tags included within the textarea contents (submitted along with the form) I obtain 403 in response. I have tried using Javascript to do some encoding on the fly but the form submission fails with the same response.  Moreover, I don't think that the file permission is an option since my web app is running a framework. The Action part of the form does not reference a .php file directly and is rather handled by a function on my controller. Had there been a file issue with the controller .php, the app would not work at all I guess.